# Opportunity.LastModifiedBy is null

Tags: apex, user, user-record

I found reference to an invalid user in a sandbox yesterday: LastModifiedById on an opportunity had a Salesforce ID that was not available in the org, and `opp.getSObject('LastModifiedBy')` returns `null`.

In the UI, the user name is Rollup Helper (which is a currently installed managed package), but the name is not clickable.

**Two questions:**

- Are users created by managed packages inaccessible to classes outside the package namespace?
- How do you retrieve such a user's name in Apex?

Answer (score 1):

I think opportunity is created/modified by managed packed at the time of installation that package. Salesforce provide an interface which can be used by managed package and if any class implement that interface, it can have a method which can perform DML operations, can call api etc. These method can be run only when you install, uninstall or upgrade package and if you perform any DML operation an mock user is created by Salesforce at run time which can not be access by any one except this method. And once page is installed neither that method nor that user is accessible again by anyway.